# How to simulate a Click on Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Making a google Chrome Extension. which can go www.google.co.uk.

then click on Gmail. But Its Not Working. Where the Problem is ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#titleee').find('Gmail').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Your selector is not correct. Is "Gmail" the Id of the button?

Comment: perhaps there's no tag named Gmail

Comment: I am very new to javascript. Could you please tell me how to trigger a Link by Text. ? i mean without Knowing the ID.

Comment: what attributes does the link have

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector to the following one:

```
 $("a:contains('Gmail')").trigger('click');
```

This will select an anchor tag that has 'Gmail' in the text

Comment: But Its Not Working for Me.

Comment: What kind of HTML element is the button/link that has the 'Gmail' text?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() 
{
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
 
 $('#titleee').find('a:contains('Gmail')').trigger('click');
  
});

Comment: Its a Link with Text 'Gmail' as we can see from the Www.google.co.uk page

Comment: make sure that you have double quotes on the main selector

Comment: Still not Working .! @ Shai Aharoni

Comment: @ArifRubayet when you hit F12 and open the developer tools do you see any errors in the console tab?